# Wrap text with <p> until the first <p> appears

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace, html-manipulation

How can I wrap from the beginning of the text in a string until the first `<p>` appears? For example, If the string is

```
this is some <b>text</b><p>Beginning of a paragraph</p>
```

I want

```
<p>this is some <b>text</b></p><p>Beginning of a paragraph</p>
```

Any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve this, but it's good form to post what you've tried so that the question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try

```
$str = '<p>' . preg_replace('#<p>#', '</p>\0', $str, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this:

```
str_replace(".","</p>.<p>", $myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If our inputs would be just as simple as the one in the question, we would start with a simple expression and a `preg_replace`:

```
$re = '/(.+?)(<p>.+?<\/p>)/m';
$str = 'this is some <b>text</b><p>Beginning of a paragraph</p>';
$subst = '<p>$1<\/p>$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n4NSES/1/)

#### Output

```
<p>this is some <b>text</b><\/p><p>Beginning of a paragraph</p>
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]